# Widget Background - Calendar Blue to Green

Tags: android, widget

I have built my first widget and want to use the standard Android 9-Patch drawable:`calendar_bgtop_blue.9.png`

This drawable is in blue. But, I need the same in green.
Can anybody transform this standard 9-Patch drawable to a green color?
HTML code for green color is: `#99C000`

The link to the drawable is [here](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider.git;a=blob;f=res/drawable-mdpi/appwidget_calendar_bgtop_blue.9.png;h=af0f466c124dab03ae9c1bd2f00ec4d883850b61;hb=HEAD).

I hope, someone can help me.

Comment: You can modify nine-patch PNG files in any bitmap editor. Just do not disturb the one-pixel-wide control frame on the outside edge. StackOverflow is for programming questions, and what you have here is not a programming question.

Comment: I know, this is the problem! I am a developer and not a designer..
But i dont find any Android designer forums ...

Comment: you don't have to be a designer nor an Android designer you just have to look up some tutorials on how to change the hue and saturation using GIMP or whatever you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in The GIMP, choose the Colors menu and pick Hue-Saturation.

Now adjust the master hue slider to about -130.0

Answer (score 1):

open your source image in some graphic editor say i used Adobe Fireworks.
once you have the image loaded ---> better save As the image to another one and later start the editing tasks as per the requirements.

Now as per the issue ---> the color needs to be changed from blue or anything existing to the green with the Hexcode just mentioned! so now select the colorFill tool ---> here set the desired color also if you know the RGB, CMYK or the HexCode for the same into the color code text field provided in the color selection dialog.

---> now select a rounded rectangle and just draw over the existing image --> well here it was simple being just a rectangle, else you may draw or edit the existing image by LiveTracing it and editing the regions. ---> save in the desired format else you may export the RAW file and use it in accordance to your requirement.